# passing NSManagedObjectContext object to a third level view controller in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to be able to pass a managed object context to the UITableView view in order to be able  to save the dates. how can i do that? and what should i add ? i connected the model and configured it with the entity Event and attribute timeStamp. here is the project, it's really simple and i don't think it will take you time to understand  since i didn't add much other than the navigationBar add button and others are basics. i did actually try to make it work but an error appears telling me that the managedObjectContext passes is nil. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1348diy589c2s0/Demo.zip?m

Comment: Nobody's going to debug/write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. You dont have model class e`Event.h(m)` . First you have to create that.

1. Go to `Demo.xcdatamodeld` select your Entity `Event` Add a new file sub class of `NSManagedObjectContext`
2. Add `#import "Event.h"`
   `#import "DemoAppDelegate.h"` to your DemoDateViewController.m
3. ```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(DemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
   Event *event =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];  
   [event setTimeStamp:[NSDate date]];
   NSError *error = nil;
     // If you have a propert called `managedObjectContext` assign `context` to it and use every where
     // self.managedObjectContext = context

     // or this is enough
    if (![context save:&error])
    {

     NSLog(@"insertNewObject error = %@", error);
    }
   ```

Comment: yes i did that. thanks. i added the following to insertNewObject:

`DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    Event *event = (Event *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    
    [event setTimeStamp:[NSDate date]];
    
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"insertNewObject error = %@", error);
    }`

but the managedObjectContext is still null. why?

Comment: You dont have a property called `managedObjectContext` in that class or you are not assigning `context` to `managedObjectContext`. See my edit check context instead of self.managedObjectContext

Comment: it worked great! Thank you! for once someone gave me an answer up to the point here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declare and initialize your managed context in the app delegate, as in the project templates, you can just get your context from there.

In your view controller import your app delegate

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
```

And access the managed context

```
context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: i added the following to the insertNewObject method in DemoDateViewController.m:

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    Event *event = (Event *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Comment: `[event setTimeStamp:[NSDate date]];
    
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"insertNewObject error = %@", error);
    }`

Comment: it's telling me that there is no instance of managedObjectContext in the appDelegate (which i'm sure there is) and there's a debugger error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Event''

Comment: You have to tell the compiler what class your delegate is. See my edit.

Comment: okay thanks it worked. now i want to add an event in order to test it. i added a few code in the insertNewObject but managedObjectContext is still null. is there an alternative way (or may my way is wrong) to add an event ? (i posted the code for this part in another comment from another user)